# How to create a text box system for a text based adventure game?

Tags: python, text, pygame, adventure

I'm attempting to create a text based adventure game for my A level Computing NEA. I want a system where text will appear on screen one character at a time, and will stay on screen until the enter key is pressed. I don't have much experience with pygame so I'm not sure how I could create something like this.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pygame, sys, random, select, os, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

size = (800,800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#main program loop

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri',100,True,False)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    text1 = font.render('Welcome.',True,BLACK)
    screen.blit(text1,[200,200])
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: Why are you using `pygame` to create a text-based game? Regardless, your question is too broad and vague for this web site.

Answer (score 0):

To add 1 character at a time, create a timer (I use threading.Timer) to add 1 character at a time to the string you want to blit. Then blit that sentence with the new character added. Something like this:

```
def Add_Character(Text=[]):
    global sentence
    sentence=''
    for letter in Text:
        timer=threading.Timer(1.0,DoNothing)
        timer.start()
        while timer.isAlive():
        pass
        sentence=sentence+letter
```

Now you blit that sentence on the screen.
Regarding pressing enter, use pygame.keys to check enter key press.
When enter pressed I would blit a portion of the background on top of the text to "delete"
it.